# Scraping a Site only works once

Tags: wordpress, web-scraping

I tried to scrape a specific field on Toys R Us's page...

http://www.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=13157031

with the selector "price".

It all worked for one time through the page load, then it never worked again. Do some sites have ways of preventing people from scraping their content? I'm kinda new to this, please be gentle. I was using Wordpress, WP-Web-Scraper, and the following as the code in the page:

```
Price:

[wpws url="http://www.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=13157031"
 selector="price" on_error="error_show" user-agent="diaperbot"]
```

Answer (score 2):

markratledge is right.  The immediate thing to consider is changing your user agent so you aren't identifying yourself.  Here's a helpful link to a list of common/most popular agents: http://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/.  Also, your IP is another big thing.  If you are scraping with only 1 IP, depending on your volume, you could get blocked quickly.  You'll likely need to use a proxy.  There are many our there ranging from free to those that charge.  I've found Ntrepid's tools to be useful (https://ion.ntrepidcorp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> Do some sites have ways of preventing people from scraping their content?

Yes, they do. They might have detected the user-agent in your query and blocked your IP.

Why? Read the TOS about downloading their content: http://www.toysrus.com/helpdesk/index.jsp?display=safety&subdisplay=terms

That WP plugin is fairly primitive. If you want to scrape sites more efficiently and with better results, use python, a language specifically designed for scraping. Check http://www.google.com/search?q=python+scraper+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

webscraper has [some issues with cache](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-web-scraper-plugin-does-not-work-cache-problems), set cacetime to 0 !